# How to get text inside the quotation mark from string?

Tags: vb.net, string, vb.net-2010

I have a string like this:

`+COPS:0,0,"XL",2` or `+CSQ: "15",99`

How can I get "XL" or "15" from the string.

On the second one, I've tried using replace and remove `+CSQ:` and `,99` but I can't do this on the first one.

Comment: A quick way would be to use RegEx and it's capture groups to extract it.

Comment: Use split function if You are certain that there are only 3 groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first string use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to split on commas then [String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to remove the quotes:

```
Dim line = "+COPS:0,0,""XL"",2"
' Split fields on comma
Dim fields = line.Split(",")
' Quote literal
Dim quote = """"c
' Use trim to remove quotes
Dim value = fields(2).Trim(quote)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same spirit as @Phillip Trelford but avoiding one step splitting on quotes :

```
Dim line = "+COPS:0,0,""XL"",2"
' Split fields on quotes
Dim fields = line.Split(""""c)
Dim value = fields(1)
```

One liner function :

```
Public Function getValue(ByVal from As String) As String
    Return from.Split(""""c)(1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regular expressions for that task.
For example :

```
Dim stringtoscan = yourstringhere
Dim expression As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(Chr(34) + "(.*?)" + Chr(34))
Dim stringMatches = expression .Matches(stringtoscan)
```